# How to apply solvent-correction to Gaussian derived Gibbs energies?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-chemistry, quantum-mechanics, statistical-thermodynamics, thermodynamics

I study reaction A + B → C + D  in a water using DFT. I think I should apply some kind of correction over RRHO because it is not true in a solvent. I found the given work (https://doi.org/10.1021/jp980229p) and got to the point of calculating that `p=1358 atmospheres`...
How could I now apply it for Gibbs free energies / reaction barriers?
Best

Comment: The answers on https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/how-to-compute-free-energy-for-solvation-using-gaussian09/10255#10255 can help?

Comment: This leads to the computations on solvation free energy. I seek on how to apply  correction to translational entropy for the solvated systems already. Gaussian, by default, assume 1 atmosphere pressure what is nonsense for a liquid such as water which as it actually 1358 times greater...

Answer (score 3):

You can set the pressure (and temperature) for thermochemistry calculations in Gaussian: https://gaussian.com/pressure/

If you want to calculate manually from the partition function, see section 2.1 of Gaussian's Thermochemistry writeup: https://gaussian.com/wp-content/uploads/dl/thermo.pdf

I'll reproduce the two equations needed here:
$$
q_{trans}=(2\pi Rm/h^2)^{3/2}(RT/P)
$$
Note that the above is the same as equation 16 in the Martin paper linked.
$$
S_{trans}=R(lnq_{trans}+3/2)
$$